# Using $(call ....) in a makefile recipe

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

So I have a really nice make macro that creates me a pretty message during compilation that is done in such a way that the destination of the message can be implemented externally.

It uses the `$(shell )` make function something like this.

```
send_msg = $(shell $do_send_msg "$1")
```

Where `do_send_msg` can be expanded to be `echo`, `wall`, `email`, etc.

I use this lots in the makefiles.

I'd like to be able to use the same macro in recipes as the result of the recipe may change what is needed to be sent, dependent on some test made to the result of an external program.

However variables in recipes are expanded by make entirely before the lines in the recipe are called one at a time.

So if I write (e.g.)

```bash
if test_prog; then \
    $(call send_msg,PASS);\
else \
    $(call send_msg,FAIL);\
fi
```

Effectively this becomes (not strictly true syntax, but close enough):

```bash
(bash -c 'echo "PASS"') &
(bash -c 'echo "FAIL"') &
(bash -c 'if test_prog; then \
    \
else \
    \
fi)'
```

This of course will not work, it will run `test_prog` and, separately, regardless of the exit status both `send_msg` lines will expand and be executed.

So it will print both **PASS** and **FAIL** as the two subshells are run independently and in parallel by make.

I don't want to 'cheat' and use another variable in the `$(call )` function or even worse a global that, ok, would allow an `if some_var ...` in the `send_msg` implementation but would reduce it's flexability as the implementation would have to understand that variable in all cases.

Another way would be to just have two different send_msg macros, one with and one without the `$(shell )` function. Simple, but not elegant.

Right now I am using a 'hack' and calling the same makefile with a variable. If that variable is set then it sends it's contents otherwise does nothing. This works fine but to me it seems clunky and wrong, there must be a better way.....
e.g.

```bash
if test_prog; then \
    MESSAGE=PASS $(MAKE) message;\
else \
    MESSAGE=FAIL $(MAKE) message;\
fi
```

Where the `Makefile` says (and this is an abreviated version to convey the idea)

```
ifneq ($(MESSAGE),)
message:
    $(call send_msg,$(MESSAGE))
else:
message:

endif
```

**Question:**
How would I make (*make*) detect if the macro is being expanded inside a Makefile recipe or inside the Makefile body and effectively keep or remove the `$(shell )` call that wraps how the work is done?

e.g. (if `make_or_shell` existed)

```
ifdef some_test
$(make_or_shell send_msg,"Message from Make")
endif

goal:
    $(make_or_shell send_msg,"Message from Recipe")
```

Comment: `bash -c echo foo` is not `bash -c "echo foo"`. You need the `foo` to be an argument to `echo`, not to the shell itself. Remember, it's `bash -c script_here argv0 argv1 argv2...`, so if the thing passed in `script_here` doesn't use `$0`, `$1`, etc it'll never see what was passed to the shell as later arguments; the script `echo` certainly never checks them.

Comment: _How would I make (make) detect if the macro is being expanded inside a Makefile recipe or inside the Makefile body_  You can't.

Comment: There is one thing you can do but it's kind of a hack.  At the very end of the last makefile you can set a variable something like `ALL_MAKEFILES_READ = 1`.  This variable will not be set until all makefiles are parsed, so anything expanded with this variable set is being parsed as part of either secondary expansion (if you have it enabled) or as part of a recipe expansion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  For the sake of a well formed question, thanks for pointing out the error and I will find time to correct it. Though the question is not about the (what is pseudo) shell script in the question it's about GNU make.  I agree it's annoying to others with similar issues when QA's are themselves incorrect.

Comment: @MadScientist In answer to your first post - I thought so - GNU Make needs an enhancement, a simple .INRECIPE variable set by make would work. Also thanks for the 2nd post, that's an interesting idea, I will give that some thought.   Actually you just gave me an idea.  If the $(shell) call and the recipes used a different .SHELL variable then you could just add a flag in the call to the shell by setting .SHELL to something useful.

Comment: Maybe.  You can file an enhancement request.  Personally I can't remember ever running across a situation before where someone wanted to expand the same variable in a different way in makefile contexts vs. recipe contexts so it's not clear to me that this is really needed.

Comment: The reason is simple. Remote logging of automated builds.

Comment: @MadScientist  I think your idea of two different .SHELL variables is a much better idea as this would have other benefits too.  E.g. where the shell for the recipe needs to be different to the shell for the makefile - allows much more in the way of cross platform and remote use cases.

Comment: It's already possible to have a different shell for a recipe, using target-specific variables to set `SHELL`.  I don't really understand why you'd want to have different shells for the makefile versus the recipe.  I think it's a bad idea since that just means that instead of one shell you'd be requiring two different shells (or more!) to be installed before you could build the software.  That would be frustrating.  I don't see how cross-platform or remote use cases play into it.  But maybe I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: e.g. in my case the default shell is tcsh.  Most of the system uses tcsh (though I hate it).  Many commands use GNU environment modules as we use all historic versions of tools (for regression testing).  If you call a GEM command in a Makefile it often breaks unless you run it in a subshell.  Also spawning subshells within shells is costly.

Comment: In the example I gave you can use a shell specific but that's adding syntax where one line would be better and easier to document.

Comment: Passed to GNU: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?63621  If you like the idea you can vote for it via the link at the bottom of the 'bug' page.